# Is my question still too broad? If yes, why?

Tags: support, specific-question

Some time ago I posted [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1215785/559711) that was put on hold as too broad. A few hours later I edited it, hoping to make it more suitable for the site.

Is my question still too broad? If yes, can someone please help me in identifying why? Is my question salvageable, or is it unsuitable "on its core"? (should I look for a forum instead?)